# find first empty row starting from a specific row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column A in my sheet like this :

```
line 1: hello
line 2: hello
line 3:
line 4: hello
line 5: 
line 6: hello
line 7: 
line 8: hello
line 9: hello
```

I would like to have a function which return for a specific row, the row of the first empty cell starting from the specific row.

For example :

If I specify row 1, I would like to get row 3 
If I specify row 6, I would like to get row 7

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you searched this site? This question (and variants) has been asked many times and I am sure one of the answers will get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: I have only found methos to search for the first empty row on all the sheet, not from a specific start position

Answer (score 0):

How about this? (assumes your data is in column A)

```
Function GetNextEmptyCell(sht as worksheet, rw As Long) As Long
    With sht //Change sheet to suit your needs
        GetNextEmptyCell = IIf(IsEmpty(.Range("A" & rw).Offset(1, 0)), rw + 1, .Range("A" & rw).End(xlDown).Row + 1)
    End With
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetNextEmptyCell(1) // prints 3
    Debug.Print GetNextEmptyCell(4) // prints 5
End Sub
```